# iphone TabBarController, how to resize it to height?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

any one know how to resize the TabBar? i want make it 80px height for use my custom background and buttons,and make it more beautiful.

*thank you*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it. Why waste extra pixels for a tab bar? Users would much rather have more room for the content. Scale your background and buttons appropriately to fit its current height.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Apple's tab bar. But you could make your own custom tab bar, which is what some other applications do.